# How to create nested form options in a Drupal content type?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I am creating a management system for a music academy. Part of that is a Content Type for a music teacher, where I have to record:

- the instrument(s) the teacher is trained in, AND
- his proficiency per instrument

The existing, hand-coded form looks like the screenshot below

[image: nested form elements]

A person filling in the form can choose an instrument from the first list, choose proficiency level from the second list, and can then click the right-pointing arrows to add his instrument and corresponding proficiency level to the box on the right. He can do this for several (or all) instruments available in the first list.

A set of choices looks like the screenshot below

[image: nested form elements, chosen]

Is there a way to accomplish the same functionality using drupal (7) and contributed modules? Any help will be a lifesaver. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems you want to to add combination of subject and level terms for particular entity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use field collection and inline entity form module for this, you can create a combination of level and subject in field collection. that can be added many times.

Comment: thanks so much for answering this for me! Let me try this out and get back to you.

Comment: The Field Collection module was exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!